# How to configure sendmail ldap routing to do a mailHost lookup for final recipient when using a mailRoutingAddress

Tags: ldap, sendmail

I am using sendmail/openldap to deliver mail within a geographically distributed cluster.  This is working for the most part, but I am having a problem with mail forwards.

When I set an LDAP mailRoutingAddress for a user that is within the same domain, sendmail does not get the mailHost for the final recipient, but performs a local delivery.  I realize this is expected bahaviour, but I need to find a way to make sendmail do an LDAP mailHost lookup (ldapmh) for the new recipient after it has done the map_rewrite for the mailRoutingAddress (ldapmra).

I am hoping someone with some serious sendmail-fu, can suggest a way that the sendmail rules can be modified to inject an LDAP mailHost lookup (see ##COMMENT in parser output).

Typical LDAP entries might look something like this:

```
dn: uid=allan, dc=my, dc=example
mailLocalAddress: allan@my.example
mailRoutingAddress: babs@my.example

dn: uid=babs, dc=my, dc=example
mailLocalAddress: babs@my.example
mailHost: east.my.example

dn: uid=chuck, dc=my, dc=example
mailLocalAddress: chuck@my.example
mailHost: west.my.example

dn: uid=diane, dc=my, dc=example
mailLocalAddress: diane@my.example
mailRoutingAddress: someuser@freemail.example
```

Here is a sample parser output

```
   mailgw# sendmail -d -bt
Version 8.14.7

###debug output redacted

============ SYSTEM IDENTITY (after readcf) ============
      (short domain name) $w = mailgw
  (canonical domain name) $j = mailgw.my.example
         (subdomain name) $m = my.example
              (node name) $k = mailgw.my.example
========================================================

ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
Enter <ruleset> <address>
> /parse allan@my.example
crackaddr(allan@my.example)
crackaddr=>` 0x81 g'
Cracked address =  0x81 g
Parsing envelope recipient address

--parseaddr(allan@my.example)
canonify           input: allan @ my . example
Canonify2          input: allan < @ my . example >
map_lookup(host, my.example) => host_map_lookup(my.example) => map_rewrite(my.example), av =
    my.example
map_rewrite => my.example.
FOUND my.example
my.example. (0)
Canonify2        returns: allan < @ my . example . >
canonify         returns: allan < @ my . example . >
parse              input: allan < @ my . example . >
Parse0             input: allan < @ my . example . >
map_lookup(dequote, allan) => NOT FOUND (0)
Parse0           returns: allan < @ my . example . >
ParseLocal         input: allan < @ my . example . >
ParseLocal       returns: allan < @ my . example . >
Parse1             input: allan < @ my . example . >
LDAPExpand         input: < allan < @ my . example . > > < allan @ my . example > < >
map_lookup(ldapmra, allan@my.example) => map_rewrite(babs@my.example), av =
    allan@my.example
map_rewrite => babs@my.example
babs@my.example (0)
map_lookup(ldapmh, allan@my.example) => NOT FOUND (68)
canonify           input: babs @ my . example
Canonify2          input: babs < @ my . example >
map_lookup(host, my.example) => host_map_lookup(my.example) => CACHE my.example
#### COMMENT: This is where I need to dip LDAP
map_rewrite(my.example), av =
    my.example
map_rewrite => my.example.
my.example. (0)
Canonify2        returns: babs < @ my . example . >
canonify         returns: babs < @ my . example . >
Parse0             input: babs < @ my . example . >
map_lookup(dequote, babs) => NOT FOUND (0)
Parse0           returns: babs < @ my . example . >
LDAPExpand       returns: babs < @ my . example . >
map_lookup(virtuser, babs@my.example) => map_rewrite(babs), av =
    babs@my.example
    babs
map_rewrite => babs
babs (0)
Recurse            input: babs
canonify           input: babs
Canonify2          input: babs
Canonify2        returns: babs
canonify         returns: babs
parse              input: babs
Parse0             input: babs
map_lookup(dequote, babs) => NOT FOUND (0)
Parse0           returns: babs
ParseLocal         input: babs
ParseLocal       returns: babs
Parse1             input: babs
Parse1           returns:  0x96  local  0x98  babs
parse            returns:  0x96  local  0x98  babs
Recurse          returns:  0x96  local  0x98  babs
Parse1           returns:  0x96  local  0x98  babs
parse            returns:  0x96  local  0x98  babs
2                  input: babs
2                returns: babs
EnvToL             input: babs
EnvToL           returns: babs
final              input: babs
final            returns: babs
parseaddr-->0xbfbfd8c0=allan@my.example:
    mailer 8 (local), host `'
    user `babs', ruser `<null>'
    state=OK, next=0x0, alias 0x0, uid 0, gid 0
    flags=180<QPINGONFAILURE,QPINGONDELAY>
    owner=(none), home="(none)", fullname="(none)"
    orcpt="(none)", statmta=(none), status=(none)
    finalrcpt="(none)"
    rstatus="(none)"
    statdate=(none)
mailer local, user babs
```

Comment: Have you considered using `virusertable` for recipient address rewrites?  `virtusertable` may be also "LDAP based" but it may conduct up to 7 lookups per recipient.

Comment: I do use LDAP for virtusertable lookups, and that works as expected. Technically, it would probably work, but it would require some fundamental changes in our overall architecture in several places that really complicates things.  It's much easier for me if it can be rolled into a sendmail.cf patch.